# Django Allowed Hosts

Tags: django

I want **only** my **front.domain.com** to access the django API so i updated my **settings.py** .
When i deployed i can access the django API via curl and postman so i'm confused here is there anything i'm missing !

**settings.py**

```
DEBUG = False  # deployment

if DEBUG:
    FRONT_OFFICE_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:4200/'
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']  # development
    CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True # development
else:
    FRONT_OFFICE_URL = 'https://front.domaine.com'
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = [FRONT_OFFICE_URL ]  # deployment
    CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [FRONT_OFFICE_URL]
    CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [FRONT_OFFICE_URL ]



INSTALLED_APPS = [
     ...
    'corsheaders',
   ]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
     ...
   ]
```

Answer (score 0):

CORS prevents browsers from accessing resources on other domains. But any other http request will not be blocked by CORS. If you need to block requests where `Referer` is not your domain, you can write some middleware to do that, but beware that it can easily be faked - Postman and Curl both lets you set the `Referer` header to any value.

If you need to secure requests to the API in Django, [setting up CSRF protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/) is the way to go.